# Cant access $.get data

Tags: jquery

```
$.get('ajax/score.php', {reason: action}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(typeof data.status);
        console.log(data.status);
}
```

produces

```
{"status":"1"}
undefined
undefined
```

Why is `data.status` returning undefined when it quite clearly is defined?

Cheers

Comment: You need to specify that it is JSON and/or parse it as JSON. It looks like a `String` to me

Comment: If you know that your are receiving JSON, then I suggest that you use `$.getJSON('url', {}, function(data) { ... });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse your JSON:

```
$.get('ajax/score.php', {reason: action}, function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(typeof data.status);
        console.log(data.status);
}
```

Comment: Also fixed by providing 'json' as a paramater after success function. Thanks

Comment: Or just call `$.getJSON()` as @jpmorin suggests above.